# Unable to create online-only I-134 for a child

Tags: usa, immigration, visa

Suppose that a person is trying to submit an online-only version of [USCIS I-134](https://www.uscis.gov/i-134) (Affidavit of Financial Support) for a relative of that person and her child. It seems that the nline version of the form does not allow a person to list people travelling with the beneficiary. It seems that it is not in the "one form for the whole family" format, at least in it's online version. Some people suggest submitting a form for each person. On the other hand, it is not possible to submit this form for a young child, since such a child does not have a passport and this form cannot be completed until one supplies a valid passport number. The USCIS call center is not  not able to answer the question.

What is the person expected to do in this scenario per the regulation? How did creators of this form intend the applicants to establish a relationship between the child and her mother?

Comment: I-134 can only be filed online to sponsor a Ukrainian for the Uniting for Ukraine program. Is this what you are filing it for?

Comment: Yes, @user102008 that's what I am trying to do.

Comment: Hi have question as well i do have a minor child with passport and i filled out the form but in passport# line it keep asking to enter only 8 digits and i have 9, even if i enter 8 still give an error and i cannot submit the form no matter what number i enter

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer to whether you can file one form for the whole family. As for the child not having a passport, the eligibility requirements for Uniting for Ukraine (see [here](https://www.uscis.gov/ukraine) or [here](https://www.dhs.gov/ukraine)) require that the beneficiary have a valid passport, or be a child included on a parent's passport. So if the child is not included on a parent's passport, then I think they would need to get a passport for the child first.

Answer (score 1):

we faced a similar problem, sponsoring a family where a child doesn't have a passport. USCIS support recommended putting the parent's passport number in the I-134 online form. I also added a note that the passport number was from the parent's passport and the child was listed in the passport. We got I-134 approved.
Hope this helps!